# count customers who generated more than 2 invoices - mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to count the number of customers generated more than 2 invoices

```
mysql> select * from invoices;
+-------+--------+---------------------+
| invId | cus_id | timeinfo            |
+-------+--------+---------------------+
|     1 |     36 | 2019-02-21 16:47:10 |
|     2 |     33 | 2019-02-21 16:49:22 |
|     3 |     34 | 2019-02-21 16:51:00 |
|     7 |     34 | 2019-02-21 19:02:46 |
|     5 |     36 | 2019-02-21 16:53:55 |
|     6 |     33 | 2019-02-21 19:02:02 |
|     8 |     33 | 2019-02-22 01:36:26 |
|     9 |     34 | 2019-02-22 16:01:20 |
|    10 |     33 | 2019-03-03 13:02:28 |
|    11 |     35 | 2019-03-05 19:11:53 |
|    12 |     32 | 2019-03-13 22:41:38 |
+-------+--------+---------------------+
11 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try like below

this will return customer id who have multiple invoice

```
 select cus_id 
 from invoices
 group by cus_id 
 having count(*)>2
```

if you need just number then use below it will return just number of customer

```
select count(*) as numberofcustomer
 from (   select cus_id 
     from invoices
     group by cus_id 
    having count(*)>2 
     ) a
```

Comment: it worked already but it is showing two customer ids.. but  I want to get the number of total customers.. it is grouped...

Comment: @YameenRabbani use 2nd query it will return number of customer

Answer (score 0):

You need to group your `cus_id` values and use `having` clause like below:

```
select cus_id, count(invId) as InvoiceCount
from invoices
group by cus_id
having count(invId) > 2
```

EDIT: If you need total number of customers, you should use the query above as sub-query:

```
select count(t.cus_id) as CustomerCount 
from (
   select cus_id, count(invId) as InvoiceCount
   from invoices
   group by cus_id
   having count(invId) > 2 
) t
```

Comment: it worked already but it is showing two customer ids.. but  I want to get the number of total customers,, it is showing customer id 33 and 34 but  I want 2.. it is grouped...

Comment: @YameenRabbani Edited my answer.